# weak convergence in hilbert space and exchanging of limits

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, hilbert-spaces, normed-spaces, weak-convergence

Question: Let $\{x_n\}$ be a sequence of elements of a Hilbert space $X$ which weakly converge to $x\in X$. Assume also that $\limsup\|x_n\|\leq\|x\|$ Show that $\|x_n-x\|\to0$.

Proposed Solution: Weak convergence gives that $fx_n\to fx$ for all $f\in X^{*}$. So in particular if I choose $f$ such that $\|f\|=1$ and $\|fx\|=\|x\|$, then $\|x\|=\|fx\|=\|\lim fx_n\|$ and now the part I'm stuck: if I can interchange the limit with the norm, then I'm done (and as a side question I'd also be curious to know when you're allowed to exchange the limit with $f$, i.e. $\lim fx_n=f\lim x_n$). But I don't know the answer to these. I also don't think I've yet used Hilbert Space, nor the sup condition.

Answer (score 2):

Let $\left<\cdot, \cdot\right>$ denote a Hilbert space inner product in $X$. Then

$$0\leq \liminf\|x_n-x\|^2 \leq \limsup\|x_n-x\|^2 = \limsup\left<x_n-x, x_n-x\right>$$ 
$$=\limsup\left(\|x_n\|^2 -\left<x_n,x\right>-\left<x,x_n\right> +\|x\|^2\right) \leq 2\|x\|^2 - \limsup (\left<x,x_n\right> + \left<x_n,x\right>) = $$$$ =2\|x\|^2 - 2\|x\|^2 = 0.$$